# Lighting and material color problems

Tags: opengl

I can't change any object color when lighting is enabled.

This is my init function (the part of the light and material):

```
glEnable (GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable (GL_LIGHT0);
GLfloat light_ambient[] = {0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0};
GLfloat light_diffuse[] = {0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0};
GLfloat light_specular[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0}; 
GLfloat light_position[]={0, -1.0, 0, 0.0};
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, light_ambient);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, light_specular);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);
```

Each object has a vector of colors. This is how I draw my objects:

```
float mat_a[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
float mat_d[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
float mat_s[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
...
colors_vect = some_object->getColor();
glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
mat_a[0] = colors_vect.at(0);
mat_a[1] = colors_vect.at(1);
mat_a[2] = colors_vect.at(2);
mat_d[0] = colors_vect.at(3);     //The values are correct.
mat_d[1] = colors_vect.at(4);
mat_d[2] = colors_vect.at(5);
mat_s[0] = colors_vect.at(6);
mat_s[1] = colors_vect.at(7);
mat_s[2] = colors_vect.at(8);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, mat_a);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, mat_d);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, mat_s);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
...
```

This code doesn't work. I tried to give the mat some random values and still nothing changes.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You're not showing the drawing code. Do you have correct normals specified for your vertices? Also, why are you enabling `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL`? With that enabled, any `glColor()` calls you might have in the drawing code would override the material colors you just set.

Comment: Enabling GL_COLOR_MATERIAL was the problem. I am new to OpenGL and some examples in the web enabled GL_COLOR_MATERIAL, so I thought this was necessary. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is caused by this line:

```
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
```

This enables functionality that allows material properties to track the current color, which is the color set with regular `glColor()` calls. If this is enabled, `glColorMaterial()` controls which parts of the material parameters track the current color. The default is `GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE`, which means that the current color is used for the ambient and diffuse material parameters.

You need to make a choice about how you want to update your material properties:

- If you need to change colors very frequently, it can be most efficient to enable `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL`, and use `glColor()` to update the material properties.
- You can use `glColorMaterialfv()`, which gives you more control, and e.g. allows you to set different colors for ambient and diffuse. For this approach, you need to keep `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL` disabled.

You used a mix of these two, where you set the material properties with `glColorMaterialfv()`, but then also enabled `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL`. This means that the ambient and diffuse material properties you set are not used. Instead the current color is used for those two properties. These properties would then change any time you call `glColor()`. If you never call `glColor()`, they would use the default value for the current color, which is white (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0).

Comment: Actually, I never called glColor(). But still, thanks!

Comment: Ah, ok. On checking again, I think enabling it makes the material track the "current color" (which is the color you can set with `glColor`), even if you never call `glColor()`. I'll fix up the answer to be more precise after lunch.

Comment: I updated the answer. I believe it correctly describes the functionality now. Thanks for pointing out the problem with the initial version.